# Is it possible to install separate signal handler for each pthread?

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, systems-programming

Let's say we have 3 threads A(main), B, C. 
I am aware that we can send signals to an individual thread using pthread_kill and mask signals in thread using pthread_sigmask. Also, I am aware signal handler is shared between threads in general.

- Is it possible to handle **Same signal** in different ways by installing different handler in each thread? If so how? 
  Say: If segfault received for B it should print something & If it received by C it should ignore & for A it should take some recovery action.
- If the thread C executes segfault instruction and no sighandler for SIGSEGV installed in the process, then the core will happen for the entire process or only for that particular thread, So that rest of the threads A, B continue to execute?
- As Signal handler is shared, if a signal is sent to the whole process using pid then which thread will execute the handler? based on priority? mask? or no algorithm just random?

Comment: Signal handlers are all shared between threads but you can write your own signal handler dispatcher.

Comment: Hi @n.m. Yes i am aware that i can write my own signal handler dispatcher. But my ask is to write different signal handler dispatcher for each thread for same Signal.

Comment: You can't. It's in the docs.

Comment: Ohk thanks, So what is the answer for 2nd & 3rd question?

Comment: The core dump will happen for the entire process

Comment: According to Posix specs, any thread can execute the handler, it is not specified which one. In Linux it's a bit different, see man pthread_signal.